# Docker local registry tries to push images to docker.io

Tags: docker, ssl, registry, docker-registry

I have created a local docker registry.  Steps I have followed.
Creating certificate files.

`mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/123.456.78.9:5000`

`cp domain.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/123.456.78.9:5000/ca.crt`

`cp domain.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt`

`update-ca-certificates`

Installed Docker registry, as given in [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v $PWD/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e 
REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key registry:2`

Pulling and pushing Docker images :

`docker pull ubuntu:16.04`

`docker tag ubuntu:16.04 mydocker_registry/my_ubuntu`

`docker push mydocker_registry/my-ubuntu`

My image push tries to access `docker.io`, so error is obvious.

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/mydocker_registry/my_ubuntu]
03901b4a2ea8: Preparing  
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

My `/etc/hosts` file looks like this

`123.456.78.9  mydocker_registry`

Here I feel I have missed some small step. I can not figure that out. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after days of reading and trying, I have fixed my problem thanks to the helps given by /r/docker [redditters](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/d6cn78/docker_local_registry_tries_to_push_images_to/) :-)

**Please note that this is working for your local domain only**

#### Creating certificate files for your domain.

Here my domain is `registry.myregistry.com`.

`openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout registry.myregistry.com.key -x509 -days 365 -out registry.myregistry.com.crt`

`mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.myregistry.com:443`

Copy certificates files to appropriate locations.

`cp registry.myregistry.com.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.myregistry.com:443/ca.crt`

`cp registry.myregistry.com /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt`

`update-ca-certificates`

#### Docker registry initialization

`docker run -d -p 443:443 --restart=always --name registry -v $PWD/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.myregistry.com.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry.myregistry.com.key registry:2`

#### Pulling and Pushing docker images to registry

`docker pull alpine:latest`

`docker tag alpine:latest registry.myregistry.com:443/myalpine`

`docker push registry.myregistry.com:443/myalpine`

No errors, its pushing successfully.

To be done is, accepting pull requests from other users in the same network.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding your registry as insecure registries.

If you are using Linux, edit your `daemon.json` under `/etc/docker`

Add

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["registry-ip:registry-port"]
}
```

And run in terminal

```sh
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Something weird. There is no `daemon.json` under `/etc/docker`, when I create one and try to restart docker after `daemon-reload` , docker failed to restart.

Comment: There could be something misconfigured in your systemd file. What do you get when you run `systemctl status docker`?

Comment: `Active: active (running)`

Comment: It seems to be running can you try pushing to your local registry? If that doesn't work, try restarting docker again.

Comment: Still no luck, I have taken a dump to port 5000, when a packet comes to my ip, it sents it to 172.17.0.2. if I use localhost, then packet is rejected.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add you your registry url in the tag, if the local registry URL is not part of your Docker image tag, by default it will push to official docker registry.

So that is why you are seeing in the push log

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/mydocker_registry/my_ubuntu]
```

so All you add to add the full path of your docker registry.

```
docker tag ubuntu:16.04 123.456.78.9:5000/mydocker_registry/my_ubuntu
docker push 123.456.78.9:5000/mydocker_registry/my_ubuntu
```

Here `123.456.78.9` refer to your local registry. if it is localhost then just `123.456.78.9` this with `localhost`

You can verify the registry access in browser if it is accessiable you will able to push.

```
https://myregistry.com/v2/_catalog
or 
http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

Comment: `The push refers to repository [123.456.78.9:5000/mydocker_registry/my-ubuntu]
Get http://123.456.78.9:5000/v2/: dial tcp 123.456.78.9:5000: connect: connection refused`

Comment: where your registry is running?

Comment: Added. you need to add your correct registry URL, if it is localhost then add localhost or somewhere then add the correct URL., also answer updaed.

Comment: And if you are adding ssl and it valid certificate you don't need to insecure flag which is risky

Comment: I have added certificate files. Still no luck

Comment: is the certificate is valid? are you able to open the link in browser? `https://myregistry.com/v2/_catalog`?

Comment: Nope, I can not access this url from any PC outside the network. This system is running in a server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199672/discussion-between-adiii-and-sachith).