# Configure GitLab Container to work with external Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab-omnibus

I have been trying to get Gitlab 16.4 to work with external nginx (all on docker swarm). I am stuck in trying to get the container registry to work.

Configuration:

- Docker swarm on ubuntu 22.
- Stack 1 - Lab - This is gitlab and GitLab runner
- Stack 2 - Nginx - Central nginx
- Network - overlay network shared between the 2
- Certificates - wild card certificates installed only on nginx. No certificate is moved to gitlab instance

Gitlab Config:

```
external_url 'https://lab.domain.com'
registry_external_url 'https://registry.domain.com'
web_server['external_users'] = ['nginx', 'gitlab-www']
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "0.0.0.0:8181"
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = [ '10.X.Y.Z', '10.A.V.C' ]

registry['enable'] = true
registry['log_level'] = "debug"
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "0.0.0.0:5000"
# Configure gitlab
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "registry.domain.com"

nginx['enable'] = false

registry_nginx['enable'] = false
```

Nginx Config:

```
upstream registry_upstream {
  server lab_gitlab:5000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name                     registry.domain.com;
  listen                          80;
  listen                          [::]:80;

  listen                         443 ssl;
  listen                         [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate                /etc/nginx/certs/domain.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key            /etc/nginx/certs/domain.com.key;
  ssl_stapling                   on;
  ssl_stapling_verify            on;
  ssl_trusted_certificate        /etc/nginx/certs/domain.com_ca.crt;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload" always;
  # HTTP -> HTTPS redirect
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/https-redirect.conf;
  
  access_log                      /var/log/nginx/$server_name/access-$log_date.log  main;
  error_log                       /var/log/nginx/registry.domain.com/error.log;
  root                            /webroot/$server_name;

 
   location /v2/ {
    add_header 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' 'registry/2.0' always;
    proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;   # required for docker client's sake
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; # pass on real client's IP
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;                                                  
                                              
    proxy_pass          http://$upstream_name;
  }
}
```

Issue:
When I try to login to registry using

```
docker login registry.domain.com -u user -p pass
```

I get error response from daemon:

> login attempt to https://registry.domain.com/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request

I have tried with both password and PAT with no difference.

I would like to avoid using bundled nginx.

NOTE - If I try logging in with incorrect credentials, it throws error saying access denied, provided password is incorrect etc etc.
This tells me the system is working otherwise.

EDIT -
Some logs I could pull out:

production_json.log

```json
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/jwt/auth",
  "format": "html",
  "controller": "JwtController",
  "action": "auth",
  "status": 200,
  "time": "2023-09-30T10:15:22.537Z",
  "params": [
    {
      "key": "account",
      "value": "root"
    },
    {
      "key": "client_id",
      "value": "docker"
    },
    {
      "key": "offline_token",
      "value": "[FILTERED]"
    },
    {
      "key": "service",
      "value": "container_registry"
    }
  ],
  "correlation_id": "01HBJSBV2B6FP6EYMZT98CHFVW",
  "meta.caller_id": "JwtController#auth",
  "meta.remote_ip": "SERVER_IP",
  "meta.feature_category": "system_access",
  "meta.user": "root",
  "meta.user_id": 1,
  "meta.client_id": "user/1",
  "remote_ip": "SERVER_IP",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "root",
  "ua": "docker/24.0.6 go/go1.20.7 git-commit/1a79695 kernel/6.2.0-1012-azure os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.6 \\(linux\\))",
  "queue_duration_s": 0.006021,
  "request_urgency": "low",
  "target_duration_s": 5,
  "db_count": 3,
  "db_write_count": 0,
  "db_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_count": 0,
  "db_primary_count": 3,
  "db_main_count": 3,
  "db_ci_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_count": 0,
  "db_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_count": 0,
  "db_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_primary_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_main_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_wal_cached_count": 0,
  "db_replica_duration_s": 0,
  "db_primary_duration_s": 0.005,
  "db_main_duration_s": 0.005,
  "db_ci_duration_s": 0,
  "db_main_replica_duration_s": 0,
  "db_ci_replica_duration_s": 0,
  "cpu_s": 0.028255,
  "mem_objects": 10716,
  "mem_bytes": 1737696,
  "mem_mallocs": 4089,
  "mem_total_bytes": 2166336,
  "pid": 650,
  "worker_id": "puma_2",
  "rate_limiting_gates": [],
  "db_duration_s": 0.00518,
  "view_duration_s": 0.00015,
  "duration_s": 0.08678
}
```

gitlab-workhorse

```json
{
  "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "correlation_id": "01HBJSBV2B6FP6EYMZT98CHFVW",
  "duration_ms": 95,
  "host": "lab.domain.com",
  "level": "info",
  "method": "GET",
  "msg": "access",
  "proto": "HTTP/1.1",
  "referrer": "",
  "remote_addr": "SERVER_IP:38228",
  "remote_ip": "SERVER_IP",
  "route": "",
  "status": 200,
  "system": "http",
  "time": "2023-09-30T10:15:22Z",
  "ttfb_ms": 95,
  "uri": "/jwt/auth?account=root&client_id=docker&offline_token=[FILTERED]&service=container_registry",
  "user_agent": "docker/24.0.6 go/go1.20.7 git-commit/1a79695 kernel/6.2.0-1012-azure os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.6 \\(linux\\))",
  "written_bytes": 2524
}
```

Comment: this may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004155/docker-local-registry-tries-to-push-images-to-docker-io

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram I have added the insecure registries, still same result.